# Bundled VSC's extension with Webpack : "command not found" for any commands

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Good day,

I'm new to webpack, and I tried to bundling my extension [vscode-ahk-manager](https://github.com/Denis-net/vscode-ahk-manager/issues/8) following the [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension).
The extension seems ok, but no command are found/executed.
On my machine, in Debug mode it worked.

Now, is published on the store, 
but no user can get it working (me neither).

This is the webpack.config:

```
//@ts-check

'use strict';

const path = require('path');

/**@type {import('webpack').Configuration}*/
const config = {
    target: 'node', // vscode extensions run in a Node.js-context  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/

    entry: './src/extension.ts', // the entry point of this extension,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
    output: {
        // the bundle is stored in the 'dist' folder (check package.json),  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'extension.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '../[resource-path]'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    externals: {
        vscode: 'commonjs vscode', // the vscode-module is created on-the-fly and must be excluded. Add other modules that cannot be webpack'ed,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
        validation: 'utf-8-validate',
        bufferutil: 'bufferutil'
    },
    resolve: {
        // support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files,  -> https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            }]
        }]
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

And this is the package.json:

```
{
    "name": "vscode-ahk-manager",
    "displayName": "AutoHotkey Manager",
    "description": "Helpful tools for working with AHK",
    "publisher": "Denis-net",
    "icon": "media/icon.png",
    "version": "0.0.7",
    "repository": {
        "url": "https://github.com/Denis-net/vscode-ahk-manager",
        "type": "git"
    },
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.34.0"
    },
    "categories": [
        "Other",
        "Snippets",
        "Formatters"
    ],
    "private": true,
    "preview": true,
    "keywords": [
        "ahk",
        "AHK",
        "AutoHotkey",
        "Auto Hotkey",
        "AutoHotkey Manager"
    ],
    "activationEvents": [
        "onLanguage:ahk",
        "onView:ahk.scripts-manager"
    ],
    "galleryBanner": {
        "color": "#000000",
        "theme": "dark"
    },
    "main": "./dist/extension.js",
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "ahk.compile",
                "title": "Compile Script",
                "category": "AHK",
                "icon": "./media/package.svg",
                "enablement": "resourceLangId == ahk"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.compile-as",
                "title": "Compile Script As",
                "category": "AHK",
                "enablement": "resourceLangId == ahk"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.run",
                "title": "Run Script",
                "category": "AHK",
                "icon": "./media/run.svg",
                "enablement": "resourceLangId == ahk"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.run-compiled",
                "title": "Run Compiled Script",
                "category": "AHK",
                "icon": "./media/run.svg",
                "enablement": "resourceLangId == ahk"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.kill",
                "title": "Kill Exe/Script",
                "category": "AHK",
                "icon": "./media/kill.svg",
                "enablement": "resourceLangId == ahk"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.run-buffer",
                "title": "Run Selected Text",
                "category": "AHK",
                "icon": "./media/zap.svg",
                "enablement": "resourceLangId == ahk"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.spy",
                "title": "Window Spy",
                "category": "AHK",
                "enablement": "resourceLangId == ahk"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.temporary-switch-executable",
                "title": "Switch Executable (Temporary)",
                "category": "AHK",
                "enablement": "resourceLangId == ahk"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.docs",
                "title": "Open Docs",
                "category": "AHK",
                "enablement": "resourceLangId == ahk"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.paste-default-docs-style",
                "title": "Paste Default Docs Style",
                "category": "AHK"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.set-tray-icon",
                "title": "Set the script's tray icon",
                "category": "AHK",
                "enablement": "resourceLangId == ahk"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.set-icon",
                "title": "Set the script's icon",
                "category": "AHK",
                "enablement": "resourceLangId == ahk"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.set-script-arguments",
                "title": "Set the script arguments",
                "category": "AHK",
                "enablement": "resourceLangId == ahk"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.remove-script-metadata",
                "title": "Clear scripts Meta-data",
                "category": "AHK",
                "enablement": "resourceLangId == ahk"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.remove-ahk-offline-docs",
                "title": "Clear offline docs cache",
                "enablement": "resourceLangId == ahk"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.scripts-manager.refresh",
                "title": "Refresh",
                "icon": {
                    "light": "media/light/refresh.svg",
                    "dark": "media/dark/refresh.svg"
                },
                "enablement": "view == ahk.scripts-manager"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.scripts-manager.suspend-on",
                "title": "Suspend",
                "icon": "./media/mute.svg",
                "enablement": "view == ahk.scripts-manager"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.scripts-manager.suspend-off",
                "title": "Unsuspend",
                "icon": "./media/mic.svg",
                "enablement": "view == ahk.scripts-manager"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.scripts-manager.pause-on",
                "title": "Pause",
                "icon": "./media/pause.svg",
                "enablement": "view == ahk.scripts-manager"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.scripts-manager.pause-off",
                "title": "Resume",
                "icon": "./media/play.svg",
                "enablement": "view == ahk.scripts-manager"
            },
            {
                "command": "ahk.scripts-manager.kill",
                "title": "Kill",
                "icon": "./media/kill.svg",
                "enablement": "view == ahk.scripts-manager"
            }
        ],
        "snippets": [
            {
                "language": "ahk",
                "path": "./snippets.json"
            }
        ],
        "configuration": [
            {
                "title": "AutoHotkey Manager configuration",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "ahk.executableFullPath": {
                        "title": "Ahk executable full path",
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "C:\\Program Files\\AutoHotKey\\AutoHotkey.exe",
                        "description": "Set the ahk executables full path"
                    },
                    "ahk.displayButtons": {
                        "title": "Show buttons",
                        "description": "Specifies whether to show buttons in the editor",
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": true,
                        "scope": "resource"
                    },
                    "ahk.scriptFolders.openInNewInstance": {
                        "title": "Open script folder in a new instance",
                        "description": "Specifies whether to open the script in a new vscode instance (clic on a TreeItem with [Ctrl] down)",
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": true,
                        "scope": "resource"
                    },
                    "ahk.onEmpty.initializeWithHeaderSnippet": {
                        "title": "Initialize with an header snippet",
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": true,
                        "description": "Specifies whether automatically call a snippet, by its name, header on empty .ahk files",
                        "scope": "resource"
                    },
                    "ahk.onEmpty.overrideHeaderSnippet": {
                        "title": "Header snippet override",
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "Default Sublime Header",
                        "description": "Override the default header snippet using the name of the substitute to be inserted (snippet must exist, in order to be called)",
                        "scope": "resource"
                    },
                    "ahk.onSave.compile": {
                        "title": "Compile on Save",
                        "description": "Activate Build on Save.",
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": false,
                        "scope": "resource"
                    },
                    "ahk.onSave.run": {
                        "title": "Run on Save",
                        "description": "Activate Run on Save (`Ctrl`+`S`)",
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": false,
                        "scope": "resource"
                    },
                    "ahk.onArgs.run": {
                        "title": "Run on Argument changes",
                        "description": "Run as soon as command line arguments are set/changed (with `ahk.set-script-arguments`)",
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": false,
                        "scope": "resource"
                    },
                    "ahk.onSearch.queryTemplate": {
                        "title": "Search Query Template",
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aautohotkey.com+ahk+${encodedSelection}&oq=site%3Aautohotkey.com+ahk+${encodedSelection}",
                        "description": "Specify the search query template used in `ahk.docs` command with selections",
                        "scope": "resource"
                    },
                    "ahk.onSearch.targetBrowser": {
                        "title": "Search Target Browser",
                        "type": "object",
                        "default": "{app: 'firefox'}",
                        "description": "Specify the browser used in `ahk.docs` command with selections. (see https://github.com/sindresorhus/open)",
                        "scope": "resource"
                    },
                    "ahk.onSearch.docsStyle": {
                        "title": "Docs Style",
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": [
                            "online",
                            "chm",
                            "html"
                        ],
                        "enumDescriptions": [
                            "search with the browser on line (enable targetBrowser and queryTemplate settings)",
                            "open the chm and automatically search for the selected keyword (faster)",
                            "open a dedicated offline browser (enable overrideOfflineDocsStylePath setting)(coming soon) "
                        ],
                        "default": false,
                        "description": "Specify with what style open the docs.",
                        "scope": "resource"
                    },
                    "ahk.overrideOfflineDocsStylePath": {
                        "title": "Override offline docs stylesheet path",
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "",
                        "description": "Set the alternative style.css path for the offline docs (leave it empty for loading the default style)"
                    },
                    "ahk.format.enabled": {
                        "title": "Enable sperimental formatter",
                        "description": "Enable a simple formatter",
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": true,
                        "scope": "resource"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "viewsContainers": {
            "activitybar": [
                {
                    "id": "ahk-manager",
                    "title": "AutoHotkey  Manager",
                    "icon": "media/dep.svg"
                }
            ]
        },
        "views": {
            "ahk-manager": [
                {
                    "id": "ahk.scripts-manager",
                    "name": "Scripts Manager"
                }
            ]
        },
        "menus": {
            "editor/title": [
                {
                    "when": "resourceLangId == ahk && config.ahk.displayButtons && resourceScheme == file",
                    "command": "ahk.compile",
                    "group": "navigation@1"
                },
                {
                    "when": "resourceLangId == ahk && config.ahk.displayButtons && resourceScheme == file",
                    "command": "ahk.run",
                    "group": "navigation@2"
                },
                {
                    "when": "editorLangId == ahk && config.ahk.displayButtons && resourceScheme == file",
                    "command": "ahk.kill",
                    "group": "navigation@3"
                },
                {
                    "when": "editorLangId == ahk && resourceScheme == file && config.ahk.displayButtons",
                    "command": "ahk.run-buffer",
                    "group": "navigation@4"
                }
            ],
            "view/title": [
                {
                    "command": "ahk.scripts-manager.refresh",
                    "when": "view == ahk.scripts-manager",
                    "group": "navigation"
                }
            ],
            "view/item/context": [
                {
                    "command": "ahk.scripts-manager.pause-on",
                    "when": "view == ahk.scripts-manager && viewItem =~ /\\.unpaused/",
                    "group": "inline@1"
                },
                {
                    "command": "ahk.scripts-manager.pause-off",
                    "when": "view == ahk.scripts-manager && viewItem =~ /\\.paused/",
                    "group": "inline@1"
                },
                {
                    "command": "ahk.scripts-manager.suspend-off",
                    "when": "view == ahk.scripts-manager && viewItem =~ /\\.suspended/",
                    "group": "inline@2"
                },
                {
                    "command": "ahk.scripts-manager.suspend-on",
                    "when": "view == ahk.scripts-manager && viewItem =~ /\\.unsuspended/",
                    "group": "inline@2"
                },
                {
                    "command": "ahk.scripts-manager.kill",
                    "when": "view == ahk.scripts-manager",
                    "group": "inline@3"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "vscode:prepublish": "webpack --mode production",
        "webpack": "webpack --mode none",
        "webpack-dev": "webpack --mode none --watch",
        "postinstall": "node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/mocha": "^5.2.7",
        "@types/node": "^12.6.8",
        "node-loader": "^0.6.0",
        "prettier": "^1.18.2",
        "ts-loader": "^6.0.4",
        "tslint": "^5.18.0",
        "typescript": "^3.5.3",
        "vscode": "^1.1.35",
        "webpack": "^4.38.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "fp-ts": "^2.0.3",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "open": "^6.4.0",
        "portfinder": "^1.0.21"
    },
    "optionalDependencies": {
        "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.2"
    }
}
```

Here is the log:

> 'C:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\denis-net.vscode-ahk-manager-0.0.7\dist\extension.js'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:510:25)
>       at Function.define._installInterceptor.i._load (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:491:111)
>       at Function.t._load (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:760:742)
>       at Function.t.getExtensionPathIndex.then.i._load (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:685:176)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:640:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
>       at Function.i [as __$__nodeRequire] (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:31:381)
>       at c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:747:60
>       at D._doActivateExtension (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:747:168)
>       at D._activateExtension (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:746:6)
>       at D. (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:742:827)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at n (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:13:621)
>       at new Promise ()
>       at n (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:13:398)
>       at Object.actualActivateExtension (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:742:529)
>       at p._activateExtension (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:479:561)
>       at define._activateExtensions.r.length.Promise.all.s.map.e (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:479:245)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at p._activateExtensions (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:479:233)
>       at p.activateByEvent (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:477:126)
>       at D._activateByEvent (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:744:680)
>       at define.$activateByEvent._readyToRunExtensions.wait.then.t (c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:753:136)

Without bundling, it works.
I want to continue the development, but I can't add code without bundling it first.

So, How can I do it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was just the vscode-ignore that was wrong.
Thank you [Sai Krishna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9839146/sai-krishna) for the edits

Comment: What was wrong with the .vscodeignore file? I would like to know because the same problem is happening to me. Thanks!